# How many observations is the minimum?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I want to estimate model transition matrix for a process (Markov chain).
How much observiations of state do I need?
I would prefer this as a function dependent on $n$, where $n$ is number of possible states.

Also, see my new question [How can I compare two Markov processes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86340/how-can-i-compare-two-markov-processes)

Comment: I guess it is related to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86331/how-can-i-compare-two-matrices) question of yours. Both are a bit unspecific, so if they are highly related I would advise you to ask 1 complete question for the sake of clarity: then chances to receive a complete answer would be higher.

Comment: [contd.] E.g. here you ask for the number of observations sufficient for the estimation. Which estimation, for which purposes? To perfectly estimate transition matrix you need infinitely many observations.

Comment: I am aware of that. I need to be able to determine this matrice with some error not greater than specified value.

Comment: @Ilya, I explained everything in my new question.

Comment: @Daenerys Was this a necessary edit? Was it even useful? Better leave some questions sleep, don't you think?